# How to filter unique records in SQL based on conditons?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data, with student id, names, education, and completion year.

How I can display only one row for each alumni, such that If an alumnui has completed more than one study program, the row of the table with the last completed study level will be retained.

Please see image below for data!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWg0A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the `GROUP BY` feature like that :

```sql
SELECT id, name, education, MAX(year)
FROM data
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: How to filter unique records in SQL based on conditons?
Answer: Condition part you can use "Where" clause and
filter unique records you can use "Distinct" or "Group By" clause.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).